# I need to jump to an id on the page but #id isn't working (content loaded via ajax)

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax call which loads some items, however I cannot jump to that id using a hashtag in url.

https://fuckedweb3.com/posts/posts:yjisjoo0jq#comments:pt8cpg0dsg

THe id is valid and after the content is loaded I do this:

`window.location.href = window.location.href` but it isn't scrolling down to that id.

Comment: The id is `comments_pt8cpg0dsg` not `comments:pt8cpg0dsg`.

Comment: I had changed it because `:` is an invalid selector.

Answer (score 0):

I could only get it working with a timeout

```
        setTimeout(() => {
            const id = window.location.href.split('#')[1].replace(':', '_');

            this.querySelector('#' + id).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        }, 300);
```